# Is there a test for same distribution for subpopulations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

Common tests include tests for same location and same dispersion. However, one can select two different distributions that, for example, have the same mean and variance and yet be distinct, like a normal distribution and a gamma distribution. Is there some way to test if two sub-populations arise from the same distribution, or failing that a test for same skewness or higher moments?

Comment: If you're also interested in **where** the distributions differ (not just **if**), check out [this 2018 Journal of Econometrics paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jeconom.2018.04.003) with R code, Stata code, and other materials [here](https://faculty.missouri.edu/~kaplandm)

Comment: @DavidMKaplan Thanks. Nice to have a reference for integral methods of comparing quantiles. It may come in handy.

Comment: Just to clarify: beyond testing if the distributions differ at one quantile ("pointwise") or a handful of quantiles (jointly) like in [this other paper](https://doi.org/10.1111/ectj.12095), the 2018 JoE simultaneously tests for differences at all possible points in the distribution, with strong control of familywise error rate (i.e., how often you get **any** false positive), even in small samples.  So, it reports ranges of values on which the CDFs have a "statistically significant" difference, and the reported ranges are **all** correct 95% (e.g.) of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classical answer for this problem is to use the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test.

However there are other ways to compute difference between two distributions, such as KL divergence or earth mover distance and probably much more.

Another possibility is what you have pointed out and to test if the models have the same skewnes or other higher moments. This can be done using models for location scale and shape where as the name suggests location scale and shape parameters of a distributions are fitted. You can then fit two models, one where scale and shape does not vary by group and another where it does and then compare fits by these models using likelihood ratio test. See for example Jones, M. and A. Pewsey (2009). Sinh-arcsinh distributions. Biometrika 96 (4), 761<80><93>780. In R, such models can be fit using vgam, gamlss, mgcv + mgcv.fam with other families and probably some other packages as well.

Comment: and Darling-Anderson test, and Cramer Von-Mises test.

Comment: and Pearson Chi-square test